# Spring MVC handling form population and submission

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have a form which I am populating using handleRequest on the controller which returns a new ModelAndView with the correct form and a model passed through. The form populates correctly.

On the same controller I have an onSubmit method which is supposed to handle the submission of the form I created. This is never called. When I submit the form the page reloads as if I have called handleRequest and nothing happens.

**Bean Definition:**

```
<bean name="/update-user.htm" class="com.leadx.web.usermaintenance.controllers.UpdateUserController" >
    <property name="sessionForm" value="true" />
    <property name="commandName" value="updateUserSelectCommand" />
    <property name="commandClass" value="com.leadx.web.usermaintenance.commands.UpdateUserSelectCommand" />
    <property name="formView" value="update_user" />
</bean>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class UpdateUserController extends SimpleFormController implements Controller  {

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Override
public ModelAndView handleRequest(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {

    final List<User> users = this.userService.retrieveAllUsers();

    final Map<String, Object> userMaintenanceModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    userMaintenanceModel.put("users", users);

    this.logger.info("Count of users: " + users.size());
    this.logger.info("Returning Update User view");

    return new ModelAndView("update_user", "userMaintenanceModel", userMaintenanceModel);
}

@Override
public ModelAndView onSubmit(final Object command) throws ServletException {

    final int userId = ((UpdateUserSelectCommand) command).getId();

    this.logger.info("Preparing to update user: " + userId);

    final User user = this.userService.retrieveUserById(userId);

    final Map<String, Object> userMaintenanceModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    userMaintenanceModel.put("user", user);

    return new ModelAndView("update_user_details", "userMaintenanceModel", userMaintenanceModel);
}
```

}

**And the JSP:**

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>User Maintenance :: Update User</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Select a User to Update</h1>
    <form:form method="post" commandName="updateUserSelectCommand">
        <table class="form">
            <select>
                <c:forEach var="user" items="${userMaintenanceModel.users}">
                    <option value="${user.getId()}">${user.getUsername()}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </table>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" align="center" value="Submit">
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm absolutely stumped with this so any help will be really really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `SimpleFormController`, you should override `referenceData()` method to populate form with the initial data. You shouldn't override `handleRequest()`, because it handles both GET and POST requests:

```
@Override
public Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request) {
    final List<User> users = this.userService.retrieveAllUsers();
    final Map<String, Object> userMaintenanceModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    userMaintenanceModel.put("users", users);  
    return userMaintenanceModel;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with annotation based controllers or do you just handle that in the initBinder?

Comment: @Scott: You can use method annotated with `@ModelAttribute` to create attributes to be pre-populated.